# Updating MySQL database by a JFrame form while refreshing the J table on the JFrame form

Tags: java, mysql, swing

[image]

I developed above form , to update MySQL database table 'employeeinfo'. Form also shows a J Table with current data in the database table 'employeeinfo'.

I coded to select J table row and get those in for to relevant text fields in the form.

But, I'm having trouble with updating the MySQL database by editing selected employees....**when I edit the text fields and hit update , database or the Jtable isn't updating **

Database do not updating and J table isn't refreshing..(may be because of database table isn't updating)

Update button ActionPerformed;

```
private void update_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    try{
        String val1 =txt_id.getText();
        String val2 =txt_name.getText();
        String val3 =txt_sname.getText();
        String val4 =((JTextField)bday_chooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
        String val5 =((JTextField)wday_chooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();

        String sql = "update employeeinfo set EmployeeID='"+val1+"',Name='"+val2+"',Surname='"+val3+"', BirthDate='"+val4+"',WorkStartedDate='"+val5+"' where EmployeeID='"+val1+"' ";

        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.execute();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Data Updated...");

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    updateTable();
}
```

updateTable Method;

```
private void updateTable(){

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM employeeinfo";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        table_empinfo.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error : "+ex);
    }

}
```

I changed coding as follows;Then It worked;
defined a variable:`String tableClick = (table_empinfo.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).toString());`and`String sql = "update employeeinfo set EmployeeID='"+val1+"',Name='"+val2+"',Surname='"+val3+"', BirthDate='"+val4+"',WorkStartedDate='"+val5+"' where EmployeeID='"+tableClick+"' ";`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). Hard code some data to replace the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String tableClick = (table_empinfo.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).toString());
```

Added above variable and changed the code as follows;

```
String sql = "update employeeinfo set EmployeeID='"+val1+"',Name='"+val2+"',Surname='"+val3+"', BirthDate='"+val4+"',WorkStartedDate='"+val5+"' where EmployeeID='"+tableClick+"' ";
```